# APNS_CERTIFICATE - Push Notification does not send in production

Tags: ios, django, python-3.x, apple-push-notifications, django-push-notifications

I've had this issue for about 2 weeks, when I suddenly stopped sending notifications in production. I am using the django-push-notifications library and by django admin I can send a test message, but it does not send messages through the system.

On my local computer, everything works flawlessly. I discovered a command to test the certificate:

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.push.apple.com:2195 -cert apns-cert.pem
```

> With this one I had the return: Timeout: 7200 (sec) Verify return
>   code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate) Extended master
>   secret: yes

So with a lot of research, I discovered that I needed to put the path of "CA":

```
openssl s_client -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/ -connect gateway.push.apple.com:2195 -cert apns-cert.pem
```

> Who was taking me to: Verify return code: 0 (ok)

However, for use in the library, I needed to put the full path of a .pem file. Then I found this command:

```
ls /etc/ssl/certs/Entrust*
```

I tested all the .pem files that were there, until I reached what appeared to have worked perfectly:

```
openssl s_client -CAfile /etc/ssl/certs/Entrust.net_Premium_2048_Secure_Server_CA.pem -connect gateway.push.apple.com:2195 -cert apns-cert.pem
```

Soon, I formatted my PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS_SETTINGS:

```
PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS_SETTINGS = {
     "GCM_API_KEY": "xxxx",
    "APNS_CERTIFICATE": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "apns-cert.pem"),
    "APNS_CA_CERTIFICATES": "/etc/ssl/certs/Entrust.net_Premium_2048_Secure_Server_CA.pem",
    "APNS_ERROR_TIMEOUT": 3,
}


IOS_VERIFY_RECEIPT_API = 'https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt'
ANDROID_VERIFY_RECEIPT_API = 'https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/{packageName}/purchases/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/tokens/{token}'
```

**Unfortunately it still does not send PUSH, and no error because I have configured it to pop errors to send by email.**

PS: Remembering that by sending a test text via django admin: OK. Sending via sandbox (debug): OK.

Comment: I'm not alone! I'm having the same problem, that is happening only in production environment! So the problem could be on the Apple's side or any kind of possible depreciation in django-push-notifications.

Comment: I discovered why it stopped working. My queryset that selects the devices to send the message, ends up bursting the error of "token invalid", for the older devices of the base. This caused a function to be canceled. I solved by looping and ignoring the error, sending device by device inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the sharing. Will check in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact it was not an SSL issue, it was a bulk upload error by the library.

The tokens registered in the system were expired and the library does not know how to work with it and canceled the action, causing no other token to be attempted. I corrected the problem by looping and ignoring the individual error by sending a test to my email:

```
 def send_push(self):
    errors = []

    # IOS
    queryset_ios = APNSDevice.objects.filter(user=self.authentication)
    for device in queryset_ios:
        try:
            device.send_message(self.subject, badge=1, sound=self.kind.sound)
        except APNSServerError as e:
            errors.append(APNS_ERROR_MESSAGES[e.status])
        except Exception:
            pass

    # ANDROID
    queryset_android = GCMDevice.objects.filter(user=self.authentication)
    extra = {'notification': self.pk, 'kind': self.kind.kind, 'sound': self.kind.sound}

    for device in queryset_android:
        try:
            queryset_android.send_message(self.subject, badge=1, extra=extra)
        except GCMError as e:
            errors.append(str(e))
        except Exception:
            pass

    if errors:
        send_mail("Push Error",
                  "Push: %s \n User: %s \n\n Errors: %s" % (self.subject, self.authentication.full_name, errors),
                  settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, ["my@mail.com"])
```